# Why do we need MinHeap for Meeting Rooms 2 Leetcode problem

Tags: algorithms, sorting, arrays, heaps

I came across this problem online which is a Leetcode premium problem. Most of the people are solving this using *Minheap*. *To me using minHeap for this seems like repetitive way to solve a problem* if we can achieve the same thing just by sorting the array based on startTimes & than checking if meeting(i).endTime > meeting(i+1).startTime. Increment if the aforementioned condition is true.

I don't have access to leetcode premium so I can't verify if the following solution would suffice.
Am I missing something here?

**Problem Statement:**
[image]

```
public int minMeetingRooms(List<Interval> intervals) {
        // Write your code here
        
        if(intervals == null || intervals.size() == 0)
            return 0;
            
        Collections.sort(intervals, (meeting1, meeting2) -> meeting1.start-meeting2.start);
        
        int rooms = 1;
        
        for(int i=0; i<intervals.size()-1; i++) {
            if(intervals.get(i).end > intervals.get(i+1).start)
                rooms++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("rooms required: "+ rooms);
        
        return rooms;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the problem statement into the question.

Comment: @Dmitry the question has been updated. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways to solve this: only sorting, only min-heaps or using both. Your for-loop is incorrect: consider input `(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3,5 )`.

Comment: What I'm failing to grasp is why do we need to sort the list for both startTimes & endTimes?

Comment: Just because multiple people use a min-heap doesn't mean that is the only way to solve the problem.  Can you make sure to ask the exact question you want answered? "Why do we need a minheap" starts from a premise that you need a minheap, which has not been demonstrated.  Perhaps you mean to ask "Do we need a minheap?" Or perhaps you mean to ask something else.  I'd like to challenge you to figure out exactly what your question is and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @UmerFarooq, I guess you mean the following algorithm: for each meeting $(s,t)$, we create two types of events: $(s,b)$ and $(t,e)$, where "b" stands for "begin" and "e" stands for "end". Then we sort all these events. We maintain the number of currently active meetings (initially 0). When a begin-event arrives, we increase the number of active meetings (since some meeting just started). When an end-event arrives, we decrease it (since some meeting just finished). The answer is the maximum number of active meeting at any time.

Comment: @UmerFarooq, with Min-Heaps it can be in the following way: we sort all meetings by their starting times. We maintain a Min-Heap, which stores the ending times of all active meetings. When a new meeting arrives, we remove the meetings which've already ended: i.e. the ones with ending time less then a starting time $s$ of a new meeting. To do this, we just repeatidely remove the minimum element from a heap, while it's at most $s$. Now, the number of active meetings is heap size + 1.

Comment: @Dmitry it seems like answer to me. If not, it would be nice to wait for clarification.